# How do I catch specific error returned by Firebase Auth, when user updates their password?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am writing an app, where I want to give the user possibility to change their password. So I have a simple `UpdatePassword.js` page, where I  invoke Firebase Authentication `.updatePassword(password)` method. As explained in the docs, this is a sensitive operation, and as such, the user needs to authenticate (if they haven't authenticated recently), in order to change their password to a new one.

This is my method:

```
const update = async () => {
    const user = await firebase.auth().currentUser;
    await user
      .updatePassword(password)
      .then(() => {
        setUpdated(true);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        //I want to handle this specific error but I don't know how
        if (
          error.message ===
          "This operation is sensitive and requires recent authentication. Log in again before retrying this request."
        ) {
          console.log("should display a modal for user to authenticate again");
        }
        console.log("error while updating pass: ", error);
        setSaving(false);
      });
  };
```

As you can see from my `console.log`s, in the case where the user needs to authenticate again, I want to display a modal, where they will sign in with their credentials again. This is not a problem and is easy to do. However, my question is, how do I catch this specific type of error where the user needs to authenticate? As per my `console.log`s, the way I have implemented it right now, I am just comparing the error message which I receive from `Firebase Authentication`, which is really not the right way to do. What if Firebase Auth change the error message to something else? Is there something like an error code which I can compare to the error thrown, and handle the exception by error code or something more safe than just a string message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you will see in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.User#updatepassword), the error that is thrown in this case (i.e. "if the user's last sign-in time does not meet the security threshold") has an `auth/requires-recent-login` error code.

So:

```js
//...
.catch((error) => {
     if (error.code === 'auth/requires-recent-login') {
         // Display the modal 
     } else {
         // ...
```